# GCD with nested Parse Queries

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, grand-central-dispatch

```
func getPosts(skip: Int){
    var query = PFQuery(className: self.parseClassName!)
    query.includeKey("posted_by")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil && objects != nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                var requestGroup = dispatch_group_create()

                for post in objects
                {
                    dispatch_group_enter(requestGroup)
                    let queryKommentar1 = PFQuery(className:"Comment")
                    queryKommentar1.whereKey("posted_to", equalTo: post)
                    queryKommentar1.limit = 3
                    queryKommentar1.includeKey("written_by")
                    queryKommentar1.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock() {
                        (commentObjects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                      //Creating UITableViewCells from data and store in array 
                      dispatch_group_leave(requestGroup)

                    }   
                }

                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) posts.")
                dispatch_group_notify(requestGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    println("All done")

                }  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, I'm not sure if I misunderstood dispatch groups, but my intention is to make two Parse Queries, targeting different classes, and create TableViewCells from the data provided. This works fine, but since I don't want the data to load when the user is scrolling the table, I want to preload the data and create the cells, and store them in an Array. Since I would like to remove any Activity Indication, and reload the table, by the time the fetch is complete I though (after som Googleing) that dispatch groups might be a good solution for this. However, "All done" is never printed in the console.

When I made a dispatch group around the outer query (entering the group just before the query, and leaving as the last line in the block) that worked fine. What am I doing wrong? Is it impossible to use this when nesting asynchronous calls?

FYI, I removed a lot of code, like creating the cells and using the data from Parse, since I would like to spare you from reading that mess.

Comment: (Unrelated to your question at hand, the notion of building the table view cells in advance is a horribly inefficient approach re memory. Your loop should build the model, and call the `reloadData` when the cell is to be created. Let `cellForRowAtIndexPath` populate the cells appropriately. _But do not build the cells in advance._)

Comment: Well, you're right. One of the 'posts' does never leave the group, though the other 5 are (there are only 6 objects in the class for now).

And thank you, I will reconsider the preloading!

Comment: All 6 are entering the group though....

Comment: I added a limit to the query, limiting it to 5 (skipping the item that never leaves the closure), and it all worked fine, so I guess there's something wrong with that particular object. I'll check my Parse Class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dispatch group pattern is basically right.

I would suggest logging some message at `dispatch_group_enter` and at `dispatch_group_leave` and see if it's getting called as you think it should and that every `enter` is offset by a `leave`.

If the number of occurrences of `dispatch_group_leave` are less than the number of calls to `dispatch_group_enter`, the `dispatch_group_notify` block will not get called.

Perhaps you have some path in that inner `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` closure that is preventing it from hitting the `dispatch_group_leave` call.

Comment: By logging I could see one item wasn't hitting the dispatch_group_leave, and I changed it's "Posted_by"-field (pointer to a user) in my Parse.com application. It suddenly worked, even though there are other posts from the same user, that works fine. Weird, but thanks Rob.